# Got a EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY symbol crash, how to track it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsarray

Here's the whole crash log.  What's the meaning of **EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY** exception notice?

I have to replace some strings about our company.

```html
Incident Identifier: 40BD3A10-43A5-4F0D-A283-218E1D3BEE46
CrashReporter Key:   3d8d75a8f5eeb7c3d28d52883b92ed4e0fb2529e
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             XxxxxXxxApp [13539]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/148C5049-8883-4E9D-BB98-5498EEA95191/XxxxxXxxApp.app/XxxxxXxxApp
Identifier:          com.Lotum.MCOLotumMobile
Version:             7.0.8.0 (7.0.8)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-01-15 11:22:25.25 +0800
Launch Time:         2016-01-15 10:41:58.58 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  16

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1840c5900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x183733f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x183faf134 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 808
3   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x100a5e830 -[LotumMobStatLogManager createLogHeader] + 1616
4   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x100a60788 -[LotumMobStatLogManager _syncSendLog:] + 204
5   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x100a6055c -[LotumMobStatLogManager _syncSendAllLog] + 604
6   Foundation                      0x184a87c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x183d2fa8c _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x183d2d028 thread_start + 4


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.632645     CFNetwork                  0x000000018473f104 TCP Conn 0x14693ab30 complete. fd: 4, err: 0
0.632689     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184740630 TCP Conn 0x14693ab30 event 1. err: 0
0.675441     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184740708 TCP Conn 0x14693ab30 started
0.792000     CFNetwork                  0x000000018473f104 TCP Conn 0x146a556d0 complete. fd: 4, err: 0
0.792032     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184740630 TCP Conn 0x146a556d0 event 1. err: 0
0.843491     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184740708 TCP Conn 0x146a556d0 started
0.871140     CFNetwork                  0x000000018473f104 TCP Conn 0x146d7ad80 complete. fd: 21, err: 0
0.872160     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184740630 TCP Conn 0x146d7ad80 event 1. err: 0
0.872462     CFNetwork                  0x000000018473f104 TCP Conn 0x1463a3150 complete. fd: 19, err: 0



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a2a8 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 240
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a28c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 212
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a75c __CFRunLoopRun + 928
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
4   GraphicsServices                0x00000001854b8088 GSEventRunModal + 180
5   UIKit                           0x0000000188e20d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
6   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x000000010002f268 main + 148
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000183b4a8b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c694fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b2c94c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b1b7bc _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407cac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184719434 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x0000000184a87c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68368 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184083028 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407cac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   WebCore                         0x0000000187b59738 RunWebThread(void*) + 456
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407cac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x00000001849a121c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   Foundation                      0x00000001849f6874 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x0000000100872a10 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 216
8   Foundation                      0x0000000184a87c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c67f48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2ece8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001836c0074 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187648a90 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 144
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187648b28 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 84
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018731e634 WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018731e544 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407cac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x000000018a271834 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x000000018a2463a8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4f8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b2a55c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 244
2   MediaToolbox                    0x0000000189bb1454 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1948
3   CoreMedia                       0x0000000186082980 figThreadMain + 272
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407cac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   WebCore                         0x0000000187b86f8c WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 272
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018731e634 WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018731e544 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.facebook.React.JavaScript
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407cac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x00000001007e7250 +[RCTContextExecutor runRunLoopThread] + 264
6   Foundation                      0x0000000184a87c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c67f48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2ece8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001836c0074 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187648a90 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 144
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187648b28 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 84
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018731e634 WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018731e544 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407cac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018407a7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fa9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x0000000100951050 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] + 176
6   Foundation                      0x0000000184a87c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c672cc __connect + 8
1   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x0000000100709640 __56-[BIMGCDAsyncSocket connectWithAddress4:address6:error:]_block_invoke + 88
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b19630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b195f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b27a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b27224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 15 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c4d4f8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b2a55c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 244
2   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x0000000100d962ec __55-[BBAPluginDataManager updatePluginListWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 84
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b19630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b195f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b27a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183b27224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 16 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68440 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183b8522c nanosleep + 212
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001836fe314 std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) + 84
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187899bf4 bmalloc::Heap::scavenge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 188
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001878998a4 bmalloc::Heap::concurrentScavenge() + 84
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018789bde4 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::entryPoint() + 100
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018789bd74 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::pthreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183c68b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183bb7560 usleep$NOCANCEL + 0
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183bd9db4 abort + 148
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018370d3f4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183729e98 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183734248 _objc_terminate() + 124
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183726f44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018372685c __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183734094 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183faf134 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding + 0
9   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x0000000100a5e830 -[LotumMobStatLogManager createLogHeader] + 1616
10  XxxxxXxxApp                     0x0000000100a60788 -[LotumMobStatLogManager _syncSendLog:] + 204
11  XxxxxXxxApp                     0x0000000100a6055c -[LotumMobStatLogManager _syncSendAllLog] + 604
12  Foundation                      0x0000000184a87c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fb28 _pthread_body + 156
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2fa8c _pthread_body + 0
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183d2d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 16 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000004   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x000000040000000a   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000106598038  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000170  x17: 0x0000000183b19a50  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016e2d3000
   x20: 0x0000000000000019  x21: 0x00000000800010ff  x22: 0x000000000001342f  x23: 0x00000001a08b4000
   x24: 0x0000000000010000  x25: 0x00000001a181f000  x26: 0x0000000080000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016e2d2f70   lr: 0x0000000183d2d530
    sp: 0x000000016e2d2ef0   pc: 0x0000000183c68b6c cpsr: 0x40000000

Binary Images:
0x100028000 - 0x102243fff XxxxxXxxApp arm64  <c8f0d8a21f0b385f890bc7a2c06f1d0e> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/148C5049-8883-4E9D-BB98-5498EEA95191/XxxxxXxxApp.app/XxxxxXxxApp
0x1200ec000 - 0x12011bfff dyld arm64  <9e98992ceed735e2ac4784cb28efe7c1> /usr/lib/dyld
...
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY` is irrelevant](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19859).  The important information is in the Exception Type (`EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)`) and the backtrace.

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1840c5900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x183733f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x183faf134 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 808
3   XxxxxXxxApp                     0x100a5e830 -[LotumMobStatLogManager createLogHeader] + 1616
```

A crash in `-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]` usually occurs when you are attempting to insert a `nil` object into an `NSMutableArray`.  I'm not sure what `LotumMobStatLogManager` is, as you haven't provided the relevant source code.  If that is an external dependency, I would reach out to the developers with this crashlog and tell them that their `createLogHeader` method is doing something to cause an exception, possibly attempting to insert a `nil` object into an `NSMutableArray` as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible reasons:

1, You are trying to insert nil into that array.

2, You are trying to insert to an index which is beyond the array's range.