# Got a ios App crashing report EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Tags: ios, crash-reports

Here's the whole crash log. What's the meaning of EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY exception notice?

I have to replace some strings about our company.

```
{"app_name":"","timestamp":"2019-07-17 10:30:10.79 -0700","app_version":"1.0.1","slice_uuid":"9614daf5-2960-37df-bd48-3cbc60980478","adam_id":1466941824,"build_version":"4","bundleID":"com.smartschool.holygraceacademy","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.3.1 (16F203)","incident_id":"CC2668C3-9ACD-423E-99D1-16DAA2D1B0E2","name":""}
Incident Identifier: CC2668C3-9ACD-423E-99D1-16DAA2D1B0E2
CrashReporter Key:   14de8b819ee0ebbbc409d7df69ca84a76869c735
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:              [6654]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A526C017-8BDF-4C5E-8583-ABB8F3060AC5/.app/
Identifier:          com.smartschool.xxx
Version:             4 (1.0.1)
AppStoreTools:       10G3
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.smartschool.xxx [1754]


Date/Time:           2019-07-17 10:30:10.4694 -0700
Launch Time:         2019-07-17 10:30:09.3683 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.3.1 (16F203)
Baseband Version:    7.70.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got a EXC\_CORPSE\_NOTIFY symbol crash, how to track it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804117/got-a-exc-corpse-notify-symbol-crash-how-to-track-it)

Comment: @GJNilsen we saw that but in our case we couldn't find any specific crash error...

Comment: In its current state, the question is too broad. You should try to recreate the crash while connected to Xcode. At least you need the full stack trace to narrow it down.

Comment: @GJNilsen we have to full stack trace ..but we couldn't post here due to word limit

Comment: You really need to provide more information if you want to get help. There is a 30,000 character limit for questions, so there should be enough for you to provide a proper stack trace. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176445/knowing-your-limits-what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-question-title-post-image/176447#176447