# Visual studio 2019 on mac crash on asp.net core project run

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to configurate an asp.net core 3.1 project on visual studio mac 2019. The project start with no problem on windows environment but in mac compile all succesfully but crash on server start.

Here a log of error:

```
Process:               dotnet [18178]
Path:                  /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Identifier:            dotnet
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        vsdbg-ui [18177]
Responsible:           VisualStudio [17314]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-02-11 14:13:13.298 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.3 (19D76)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        82B589AD-29DC-9E76-4268-C055B4600946


Time Awake Since Boot: 19000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information: abort() called
```

Dotnet 3.1 SDK and visual studio 2019 (mac) installed on mac.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804117/got-a-exc-corpse-notify-symbol-crash-how-to-track-it

Comment: Thanks for reply. I saw the link post before ask this question. Maybe i think it's about mac / visual studio configuration or dotnet issue because project start successfully on window environment.

Comment: It may have to do with alignment.  The link is saying you are getting an array exceeding the memory space allocated.  If the alignment is not correct for the type of microprocessor you are using you can get access errors exceeding the memory assigned.  So check your project settings and see if you are using ANY CPU or if you are using x86.  Either of these modes should solve the issue.